# Website that displays chords on a keyboard

Tags: learning, harmony, chord-progressions, keyboard

Is there a website / online service that **displays on a keyboard** the keys to use for a chord **progression**?

*It's not for me (I know how to play chords, and had some jazz courses before), but it's for a friend who asked me `Can you show me how to play this progression`?*

I'm looking for the easiest solution to show him by email (not easy!).

```
Example user input : AbM7 AbM7 Bb Gm Ab ...

Example output of the website : keyboard images with the keys to use highlighted 
                                (for each chord)
```

**Does such a website exist ?** (without having to install a software on computer)

---

*Example for Abm7 (I haven't found an image for AbM7):*

[image]

Comment: I don't know of a website, and I know you explicitly asked for a solution without software, but if you can record midi, http://www.synthesiagame.com/ would work, though not as simple as what you're asking for. This would definitely be a cool thing for someone to build though.

Comment: I was wondering about making an iPad app for this the other day (I'm a software developer)

Comment: There's also multiple ways to voice each chord so just because it shows you a chord does not mean it will sound the way you want it to.

Comment: Agreed with Dom, that's why using midi or something will like you produce exactly what keys to hit, especially if you are intending on using a specific inversion or have something other than the root in your left hand.

Comment: @Dom I totally agree about different voicings. Then it could be interesting to have a `abc music notation` to `keyboard image` converter. I suggested the idea here : https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs/issues/28 ... About `abc notation` : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_notation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a tool made just for this:

http://www.michalpaszkiewicz.co.uk/chordprogressiontool/

The program is open source too, so you can take the code and do what you like, or improve upon the project itself.

Comment: That is a cool program.  Is there a way to subtract a chord if you add the wrong chord?

Comment: Really great! Some ideas here to turn into a very useful tool: https://github.com/MichalPaszkiewicz/chordprogressiontool/issues/3 ... Would be interesting to be able to send by email to someone a chord progression

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try to incorporate them ASAP. Hopefully should be ready today 2pm GMT :)

Comment: All done, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close, but not exact. This site has a good amount of chords under separate urls.

http://classpiano.com/chord-dictionary/

You could send your friend:

AbM7 : http://classpiano.com/a-flat-maj7-chord/

AbM7 : http://classpiano.com/a-flat-maj7-chord/

Bb : http://classpiano.com/b-flat-chord/

Gm : http://classpiano.com/g-m-chord/

Ab : http://classpiano.com/a-flat-chord/

If you're a little more savvy, you could save your own offline version of all the urls to the chords, and built them without having to navigate as much, too.